# How to get the complete list of pages titles from wikipedia ?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikipedia-api

I want to get this list to later work on it for linquistic researches.

The [API:Allpages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aAllpages) [is limited to 500 queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apfrom=Kre&aplimit=500). I need them all (4millions).

Maybe attack it using dbpedia.

Any trick to do it ?

Comment: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html (for personal or noncommercial use only)

Comment: The first page contains 500 results, but you can get the next one by following the `query-continue`.

Comment: Downloading 4M results 500-by-500 will take you days...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wikimedia Foundation, which runs Wikipedia, posts periodic dumps of all their projects to http://dumps.wikimedia.org.

You can browse the latest enwiki dump (as of this posting) here: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20130204/.

The file which is probably most interesting to you is this list of all page titles: http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20130204/enwiki-20130204-all-titles-in-ns0.gz.

Comment: Thanks Nneonneo. I actually found it by myself thanks to your comment upper, but I'am happy to validate your answer ! You gave me the trick!